# Derivative of trigonometric function help

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having trouble computing derivatives at $x=2k \pi$.

Let $f(x)=x \sqrt{1-\cos(x)}$.

Then $\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{2(1-\cos x)+x\sin x}{2\sqrt{1-\cos x}}$.

Then $\displaystyle f'(2k\pi)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 2k\pi}\frac{2(1-\cos x)+x\sin x}{2\sqrt{1-\cos x}}$.

I know limits such as $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow o}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$, but I don't know how to use it here correctly.

Comment: Your calculation of the derivative is not entirely right: Check the first term in the numerator.

Comment: Using the trigonometric identity $1 - \cos x = 2 \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$, you can write $f(x) = \sqrt{2}\cdot x\lvert \sin \frac{x}{2}\rvert$. That should make it easy to see that $f$ is not differentiable in $2k\pi$ for $k\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x$ approaches $2k\pi$ from the negative side, $\sin x$ is negative.  From the positive side, $\sin x$ is positive.  We have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2k\pi^-}\dfrac{2(1-\cos x)+x\sin x}{2\sqrt{1-\cos x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2k\pi^-}\dfrac{2(1-\cos x)-x\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}{2\sqrt{1-\cos x}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2k\pi^-}\sqrt{1-\cos x}-\dfrac{x\sqrt{1+\cos x}}2=-k\pi\sqrt2$$

The positive side is similar except $\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ instead of $-\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ yielding $k\pi\sqrt2$.  The limit as $x$ approaches $2k\pi$ exists when these 2 are equal, when $k=0$.

Comment: Nice! I like how you don't rely on for me less known trigonometric identity.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In light of Daniel's comment, you can use the definition of $f'(x)$ to find $f'(2k\pi)$. Indeed, $$f'(2k\pi)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(t+2k\pi)\sqrt{1-\cos(t)}}{t}$$ Clearly, if $k=0$ then $f'(0)=0$ and if $k\neq0$ the the above limit doesn't exist so $f'(2k\pi)$ is undefined in that cases.

[image]

Comment: Now that I found out that derivative at this point I would be required to examine how it behaves around this point. So I have to evaluate $$f'_{-}(2k\pi)=\lim_{t\to 0_{-}}\frac{(t+2k\pi)\sqrt{1-\cos(t)}}{t}$$ and $$f'_{+}(2k\pi)=\lim_{t\to 0_{+}}\frac{(t+2k\pi)\sqrt{1-\cos(t)}}{t}$$ I am trying to solve it at the moment...

Comment: @cryogenic: Reflect Daniel's leading enough way. It finishes the problem.

Comment: I am sorry it takes me so long.
$$f'_{+}(2k\pi)=\lim_{t\to 0_{+}}\frac{(t+2k\pi)\sqrt{1-\cos(t)}}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0_{+}}\frac{(t+2k\pi)\sqrt{2}|\sin\frac{x}{2}|}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0_{+}}\frac{(t+2k\pi)\sqrt{2}|\sin\frac{x}{2}|}{\frac{t}{2}}\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{2}k \pi$$ and then also $$f'_{-}(2k\pi)=\lim_{t\to 0_{-}}\frac{(t+2k\pi)\sqrt{1-\cos(t)}}{t}=-\sqrt{2}k\pi$$
Is this alright?

Comment: @cryogenic: YES! Exactly! you got it right. :-)